# Most concise way to disable copying class in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

I have a problem dealing with deprecated since C++11 default generation of copy constructor and copy assignment operator when there is a user-defined destructor.

For most sufficiently simple classes default-generated constructors, operators and destructor are fine. Consider the following reasons to declare destructor:

1. Making trivial destructor virtual in base class:

   ```
   // header
   class Base1 { public: virtual ~Base1() = default; };
   class Base2 { public: virtual ~Base2(); };
   // source
   Base2::~Base2() = default;
   ```

   Would all 4 copy and move special methods be generated by compiler in these cases? If yes, then I think it is fine and there is no need to complicate `Base1` or `Base2`.
2. Printing debug message in destructor:

   ```
   // header
   class D { public: ~D(); };
   // source
   D::~D() {
   #ifdef DEBUG_THIS
       std::cout << "D was destructed." << std::endl;
   #endif
   }
   ```

   I believe that in this case copy constructor and assignment operator would be generated; but move constructor and assignment operator would not. I want to avoid using deprecated default-generating and disable copying of `D`. I also want to avoid flooding `D` with 4 `deleted` declarations. Is disabling only one copy constructor enough? Is it a good style?

Comment: I don't get what your talking about deprecation. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: In standard-C++-land you can just inherit from a non-copyable class, such as `boost::noncopyable`. With Visual C++ you might consider a macro that adds private declarations, to avoid sillywarnings.

Comment: @stefan, *The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor or user-defined copy assignment operator.* since C++11 (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-defined_copy_constructor).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Not all programs depend on boost. I also dislike macro and would prefer to avoid it if possible. I hope that C++11 provides a better way.

Comment: @user1673789 And in what way does this bother you? If you want copy to be disabled, `= delete` it explicitly (so it's crystal clear to anyone reading it). If you want copy to be enabled and you want the compiler to generate it for you, use `= default`.

Comment: @stefan, I believe that most logical behavior is not just *deprecating* default-generating but *disabling* it if there is at least one (out of 5) user-defined special method. But it was not done in C++11 to preserve backwards compatibility. My classes are very simple and I want to achieve clear and consistent behavior in the most elegant way. Neither macro nor boilerplate code meets this requirement.

Comment: @user1673789 and `= delete/default` is boilerplate to you? In that case noone can help you.

Comment: @stefan, if I have to explicitly delete all 4 methods in each simple class that happens to need almost trivial or trivial destructor, then yes, I consider it a boilerplate. Even if I have to delete 2 of them (copying), it is still not good. One thing that bothers me a lot about these constructors and operators is the need to specify parameter type and modifier (const reference or rvalue reference). I actually prefer a macro over boilerplate if there is no better solution.

Comment: You could make a non copyable class and derive from it. In my opinion it is much more readable and clean than defining a macro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Only copy constructor and copy assignment operator will be generated when destructor is explicitly defaulted. And even then their generation is deprecated. So, in order to have virtual destructor and all default methods, one should write the following:

   ```
   struct Base
   {
       Base()=default;
       virtual ~Base() = default;
       Base(const Base&)=default;
       Base& operator=(const Base&)=default;
       Base(Base&&)=default;
       Base& operator=(Base&&)=default;
   };
   ```

   I would definitely use a macro for more than one such `Base` class.
2. In case when destructor is *defined* by user, 2 special methods are still generated. There are the following ways to *disable* deprecated generating copy constructor and copy assignment operator:

   - delete move constructor OR move assignment operator (not quite self-explanatory but very short):

     ```
     Base(Base&&)=delete; // shorter than deleting assignment operator
     ```
   - delete *both* copy constructor and copy assignment operator:

     ```
     Base(const Base&)=delete;
     Base& operator=(const Base&)=delete;
     ```

   Note that you have to explicitly declare default constructor if you need it, e.g. `Base()=default;`.

   Macro or inheriting special class can be used as well for this purpose but I personally prefer deleting move constructor to implementing my own macro or base class. When using *Qt* or *boost*, I would prefer `Q_DISABLE_COPY(Base)` and inheriting `boost::noncopyable` respectively, because they are already implemented, widely known and recognizable.

http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1896 - detailed explanation and rationale for these issues.

Answer (score 20):

With C++11, a clean way is to follow the pattern used in boost (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable))

You basically create a base class where copy constructor and copy assignment are deleted, and inherit it:

```
class non_copyable
{
protected:
    non_copyable() = default;
    ~non_copyable() = default;

    non_copyable(non_copyable const &) = delete;
    void operator=(non_copyable const &x) = delete;
};

class MyClass: public non_copyable
{
...
}
```

Comment: To make this `non_copyable` class generally usable you need to add the relevant special member functions that now are not generated.

Comment: I agree that inheriting `non_copyable` is a good idea in case of big number of small classes. However (the title of my question) != (the entire question). There are several questions actually, and most of them are still unanswered.

Comment: Why the destructor is explicitly set as default?

Answer (score 13):

Deleting the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator is the simplest and clearest way to disable copying:

```
class X
{
    X(X const &) = delete;
    void operator=(X const &x) = delete;
};
```

I don't follow what you are talking about with virtual destructors in the question body . It sounds like you're asking for a way to make your code take up fewer characters of source code, but also be more cryptic to anybody looking at it.

If the list of deleted functions bothers you, you could hide them behind a macro, I guess.

```
 #define NON_COPYABLE_NOR_MOVABLE(T) \ 
      T(T const &) = delete; \
      void operator=(T const &t) = delete; \
      T(T &&) = delete;
```

Comment: If you're not working on a compiler that supports the `=delete` syntax, I would strongly recommend using the macro. Not only is it more readable (helpful for groking code at a glance), but it is also *searchable*, in a way that a list of private functions is not.

Comment: 1. It is often necessary to provide virtual destructor for a class that is inherited. I asked if all 4 default constructors / assignment operators would be generated for `Base1` and `Base2`. If *yes*, then there is no need to explicitly declare or delete any of them (if there is no other-than-consistency reason to disable copying or moving).

Comment: 2. Is explicit deleting only one copy constructor enough? Or maybe explicit deleting move constructor? Judging from answers and comments, I am afraid that it is necessary to explicitly delete at least 2 special methods (boilerplate or macro or inheritance) :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by this(which is used by [Caffe: a fast open framework for deep learning](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe)):

```
// Disable the copy and assignment operator for a class.
#define DISABLE_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(classname) \
private:\
  classname(const classname&);\
  classname& operator=(const classname&)
```

Usage example:

```
class CNoCopyable{

    public:
        CNoCopyable(int i):m_d(i){}

    private:
        int m_d;
        // add this line(pass class name)
        DISABLE_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(CNoCopyable);

};
```

Comment: This is the old way of doing the same. Is it still the best way after C++11? Hope not.