# C++ Reference passing

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have been using C# for around a year and have recently been testing my patience with the harsh world of C++.

I am trying to create an object orientated binary tree. I have stepped through the code and read up on reference parameter passing and use of const in C++ but cannot work out what I am doing to cause an Access Violation Error. I have ensured that the structure is created properly and the code completes the first line of main as expected, however calling toString seems to result in an error and I cannot work out why.

Here is the code so far:

```
// ExpressionCL.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

template<class TData> class TreeNode
{

private:
    TData Data;
    const TreeNode<TData>* Left = nullptr;
    const TreeNode<TData>* Right = nullptr;

    void setData(TData data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

public:
    TreeNode<TData>(TData data)
    {
        setData(data);
    }

    TreeNode<TData>(TData data, const TreeNode<TData>& leftNode, const TreeNode<TData>& rightNode)
    {
        setData(data);
        setLeft(leftNode);
        setRight(rightNode);
    }

    void setLeft(const TreeNode<TData>& leftNode)
    {
        Left = &leftNode;
    }

    void setRight(const TreeNode<TData>& rightNode)
    {
        Right = &rightNode;
    }

    TreeNode<TData> getLeft() const
    {
        if (hasLeft())
        {
            return Left;
        }
    }

    TreeNode<TData> getRight() const
    {
        if (hasRight())
        {
            return Right;
        }
    }

    TData getData() const
    {
        return Data;
    }

    bool hasLeft() const
    {
        if (Left != nullptr)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool hasRight() const
    {
        if (Right != nullptr)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    string toString() const
    {
        string treeString = "";
        if (hasLeft())
        {
            treeString += Left->toString();
        }
        treeString += to_string(Data);
        if (hasRight())
        {
            treeString += Right->toString();
        }
        return treeString;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TreeNode<int> IntTree(1, TreeNode<int>(1), TreeNode<int>(2));
    cout << IntTree.toString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Some guidance or further recommended resources would be great.

Comment: You're confused between pointers and references >o<

Comment: Storing pointers to temporaries is going to give you a bad time.

Comment: And the code should not compile as written, at least if you had warnings switched on (and to error), as you really should. `getLeft` and `getRight` have paths without a `return` statement.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig failure to return does not require a compilation error or warning.  OP should still fix those functions of course.

Comment: another thing is that `hasLeft()` could be written as `return Left != nullptr;`. This will improve code readability greatly.

Comment: in fact `getLeft` should not compile because the return type is `TreeNode` but the value returned is a pointer!  (actually my compiler does not diagnose this error unless `getLeft` is actually called, not quite sure why)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Which widely used compilers will not emit a warning here if invoked with their equivalent of `-Wall`? (My point was: Always use `-Wall -Werror` or whatever your compiler's equivalent is.) As for why the error is only diagnosed when you refer to (not necessarily call) `getLeft`: It's a template function and thus only gets instantiated when needed. You can write classes with functions that don't work for all possible template arguments, and that's a good thing.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig presumably none of them, since the function is not instantiated it shouldn't have its return paths checked..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setLeft` and `setRight` functions set off alarm bells. Storing the address of an object that was passed by reference is seriously asking for trouble, as the caller may destroy the object and then you are left with dangling pointers for `Left` and `Right`.

In fact that is exactly what you do. You pass temporary objects to your constructor, storing their address in `Left` and `Right`. Then you call `IntTree.toString()` which tries to use pointers to objects that no longer exist.

---

To fix this you need to need to use manual lifetime management for your nodes. That means the node must be created via `new`.  You have the option of either using raw pointers (in which case you would document your interface carefully to note that the caller should call `new`, pass in the pointer, and not call `delete` after).

The other option is to use smart pointers which will track ownership of the objects, however you have a few other problems to solve before doing that.

Specifically, `treeNode` does not currently follow the [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Fixing this is extremely important. At a minimum, [disable copying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23710728/1505939) so that you do not accidentally make copies of a `treeNode` (which will not behave properly until you start following the Rule of Three)).

Using smart pointer classes means you can follow Rule of Zero instead of Rule of Three which makes for much cleaner code (although it may be difficult to do straight off the bat if you're new to C++, there aren't any good online teaching resources that I know of besides SO).

Comment: Yep. Ideally the OP needs a move ctor on his treenode type and then just take everything by value, but that's probably a bit optimistic if he's just now learning.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yep, pointers will still need to be used inside `treeNode` though

Comment: I read somewhere that objects should be passed by reference so that you don't end up copying the object and in fact access the one originally created by it's address which makes sense. I have also read that objects created via new in C++ have to be manually deleted and hence you create them on the stack without new so that they get harvested without manual memory management (RAII or something). I did suspect that the arguments might be going out of scope but I can't see how to assessor and mutator methods any other way. Does that make any scene or have I misunderstood something fundamental.

Comment: @EdwardJBrown you *don't* want your stack objects to be "harvested" here because you want them to survive in your tree. The temporary objects `TreeNode<int>(1)` etc. are destroyed after the following `;` , before the next line.  The `TreeNode` structure should be designed to take ownership of its children, so using stack objects is not appropriate.  (LRO points out that if you implement move semantics then you can invoke your function with stack objects, and the tree will create new manually-managed objects by using a move operation, but that isn't necessary at this stage).

Comment: Yes, `treeNode`'s destructor will have to `delete` its children.

Comment: Note for clarity: Don't call `delete` on smart pointers. And: Use smart pointers. Scott Meyers and Herb Sutter actually have good material on the wide topic of smart pointers.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig I was referring to the option where the class continues to use raw pointers for its children.  (Smart pointers is the best long term solution although it can be daunting for the newbie to write a tree with smart pointers)

Comment: @Matt McNabb: On the contrary: In my experience, smartpointers are much easier to learn for beginners, because especially `shared_ptr` behaves very similar to reference types in java and c#. My general advice: Don't teach beginners how to use `new` and `delete` at all. First teach them to use `std::make_unique` and especially `make_shared` and only after they got used to it explain the actual mechanics behind that (you also wouldn't teach a c++ beginner, how `new` internally calls `malloc`).

Comment: Also, in the presence of smart pointers and move semantics, the rule of three is pretty much outdated: You e.g. often need to define a copy constructor and an copy assignement operator (possibly also the move versions) but no destructor. The rule of three was a good guideline, when it was correct for almost all code. A lot of people (including Scott Meyers) tried to port that rule into modern c++ (Rule of Five/three/Zero ...) but in my opinion they tend to confuse more than they help and the reality is: you have to decide on a case by case basis, which of the special functions you need.

Comment: @MikeMB Right, I'm just using the term as it is well known and any introduction to the topic is better than nothing. I agree in general about new and delete, but in this specific case both approaches seem viable.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I wasn't trying to contradict what you said, just to point out a potential misunderstanding readers might have – and then added that I really think Edward should be using smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the Treenode constructor with temporary values and storing in the treenode pointer to these temps.
After the constructor has finished, these temps are gone and in calling a function which uses pointers to those temps (toString), a crash is occurring.

Your design needs the values of the treeitems as long as the tree is used, because you store only pointers to those values in the tree.
You could change the design to store copies of the treenodes within the tree.